# Ignore a SELECT LIKE statement if an identical one has already been satisfied.

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, fuzzy-search

I have a table with 4 entries.

```
    CREATE TABLE tab( 
    name Text 
                    ); 

    INSERT INTO "tab" VALUES('Intertek');
    INSERT INTO "tab" VALUES('Pntertek');
    INSERT INTO "tab" VALUES('Ontertek');
    INSERT INTO "tab" VALUES('ZTPay');
```

Pntertek & Ontertek are fuzzy duplicates of the correctly spelt Intertek. I wish to create a list consisting of fuzzy duplicates and the correctly spelt names.

As I have 4 names, I have 4 search criteria:

```
    SELECT name FROM tab WHERE name LIKE '%ntertek' 
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE name LIKE '%ntertek') >1;
    SELECT name FROM tab WHERE name LIKE '%ntertek' 
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE name LIKE '%ntertek') >1;
    SELECT name FROM tab WHERE name LIKE '%ntertek' 
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE name LIKE '%ntertek') >1;
    SELECT name FROM tab WHERE name LIKE '%TPay' 
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE name LIKE '%TPay') >1;
```

This produces 3 lists containing the same information. I would like to ignore the 2nd and 3rd identical SELECT statements if the first one returns a result. Is this possible using SQLite and how would I do this?

I'm very much a beginner when it comes to sqlite and programming in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the query to return? Just potential duplicates? If so you could do the above with one query by including a having statement. However, the method that you are using at the moment only allows for differences at the start of the name. I would suggest looking into something like an edit-distance algorithm (sometimes referred to as Levenshtein distance) to identify the number of characters you would need to change on one field to make it the same as another.

There are details of a possible SQLite implementation in the following link: http://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html

Comment: I've just resorted to removing duplicate SELECT code lines using excel.

This was just an example of criteria I could use, I have a much more rigorous search process planned, thank you though.